# Scrapy url crawl path history

Tags: path, scrapy, history

Is there a way in scrapy to keep track of how a url is reached?
Ex. when url https://test.com/resource_1/resource_2/resource_3/target is downloaded, I need to get a history of how scrapy got there, along with the redirects.

```
[https://domain1.com/,
           .
           .
 https://test.com/resource_1/resource_2/,
 https://test.com/resource_1/resource_2/resource_3/]
```

Comment: It's all in the logs that it outputs by default...

Comment: Where exactly? Even if it is available in the logs, I want to access this info so that I can store the history list of url in the database, along with the results of the scraped url

Comment: You question is far to vague and you haven't shown that you have even bothered to do any research or attempt to implement this yourself....

Comment: The question is simple. For every response downloaded by scrapy, I want to keep an array with all the links followed to get there. And I have done much research